# nuget.exe push to local source (folder) error

Tags: nuget

I'm just starting with nuget and nuget.exe which is on my path (VS 2010, Win 7).
I've created a test package and have created an additional package source using the Library Package Manager in VS:
  Name: MyLocal
  Source: D:\usr\nuget\MyLocal

All I did here was create the folder on my D: drive then add the source in PM.

I'm trying to push my test package into my local source:

nuget.exe push MyTest.1.0.nupkg 99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999 -src MyLocal

...but I get 
Invalid URI: the format of the URI could not be determined.

I've tried other combinations:

nuget.exe push MyTest.1.0.nupkg 99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999 -src d:\usr\nuget\myLocal
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is the significance of the access key?
I'm obviously missing some fundamental insight. Can you help?
thanks
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't supported right now. You should just do a file copy

Comment: What is the status on this now? I am trying to do it, but am running into errors.